# Can't get information from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have this json file called gameupdater.json

gameupdater.json:

```
{ "730":{
    "success":true,
    "data":{
       "price_overview":{
          "currency":"EUR",
          "initial":1399,
          "final":937,
          "discount_percent":33
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a javascript file that has the following code:

```js
var updater = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('gameupdater.json'));
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(updater, null, 4);

var num = updater.730.data.priceoverview.initial;

console.log(num);
```

Yet whenever I run it (node bot.js) in CMD.
It does not give me what I am looking for, which is 1399.

It instead gives me this error:

```
var num = updater.730.data.priceoverview.initial;
             ^^^^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Oh, I'm pretty sure it would be hard to change stuff, since this array is going to be automatically downloaded from this website:
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a number with the dot syntax. You need to use the brace syntax, and access it as a string:

```
updater["730"].data...
```

Or, if the property is entirely a number, you can also use a bare number, but again, it must be inside the square braces:

```
updater[730].data...
```

Comment: Wait, that actually fixed the error I was having! thanks a lot man!

Comment: @AhmadOthman If this fixed your issue and helped you, you can accept this answer and give it an upvote.

Comment: I cannot accept yet, I need to wait 10 minutes. But I sure will once those 10 minutes are gone.

Comment: There's another answer now. If you find it answers your question better, you're free to accept that one as well. I'd certainly appreciate an accept though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Saw your answer only after I posted mine, was writing it down... +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use *dot* operator to access *properties* of an object if it starts with a *number* - you must use the *bracket notation*`[]`.

See the *Dot Notation* section in this MDN link - [`Property Accessors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a
>   sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore
>   ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number

See demo below:

```js
var updater = {
  "730": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "price_overview": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "initial": 1399,
        "final": 937,
        "discount_percent": 33
      }
    }
  }
};

var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(updater, null, 4);

var num = updater['730'].data.price_overview.initial;

console.log(num);
```